# How to count points for a selected variable in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

**My goal:**

I need to know how many points has the person "kll2".
What is the best way to do it?

When I write this code I get NA as an answer.

```
comp <- dataset%>%
subset(person == "kll2") %>%
summarise(sum_kll2 = sum(points))
comp
```

My "dataset" looks like this:

```
id   person   points
201  rt99   NA
201  rt99   3
201  rt99   2
202  kt     4
202  kt     NA
202  kt     NA
203  rr     4
203  rr     NA
203  rr     NA
204  jk     2
204  jk     2
204  jk     NA
322  knm3   5
322  knm3   NA
322  knm3   3
343  kll2   2
343  kll2   1
343  kll2   5
344  kll    NA
344  kll    7
344  kll    1
```

Comment: `sum(df$points[df$person == 'kll2'])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  subset(person == "kll2") %>% 
  summarise(kll2_sum = sum(points, na.rm = T))
```

Data

```
df = structure(list(id = c(201L, 201L, 201L, 202L, 202L, 202L, 203L, 
203L, 203L, 204L, 204L, 204L, 322L, 322L, 322L, 343L, 343L, 343L, 
344L, 344L, 344L), person = c("rt99", "rt99", "rt99", "kt", "kt", 
"kt", "rr", "rr", "rr", "jk", "jk", "jk", "knm3", "knm3", "knm3", 
"kll2", "kll2", "kll2", "kll", "kll", "kll"), points = c(NA, 
3L, 2L, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 5L, NA, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
5L, NA, 7L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L
))
```

Comment: When I use this I get NA as an answer.

Comment: It is giving me 8 as the answer. If your data contains NA you will get the sum as NA unless you use `na.rm = T`. See my updated code.